# Do we need to write string name resources tag separately?

Tags: android, resources

Since, the text displayed on the button is hard coded. I am trying to pass the string through resources to the text of the button.I learned that we can add it through the resources of string.xml.

I added the resources tag separately, it gave errors. So, I added in the same place, it's still showing errors. As the errors are visible already so I did not compile. The red line error is on these words:
 name="I am the passed string for the button. But, I don't know how to go there?">

```
<string name="app_name">Wednesday</string>

<string name="I am the passed string for the button. But, I don't know how to go there?">chocobar</string>
```

I want this text to be displayed on Button. This is a static text.

[image: Image Preview]

Comment: Just define it as `string name="chocobar">I am the passed string for the button. But, I don\'t know how to go there?</string>` . You have to escape apostrophe here .

Answer (score 2):

You can't use white and some special character inside `String.xml` key, you'll be able to white space in value, here is solution.

```
<string name="app_name">Wednesday</string>

<string name="chocobar">I am the passed string for the button. But, I don't know how to go there?</string>
```

try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the text you need to show in the button inside the `<string>` tags.

```
<string name="chocobar">I am the passed string for the button. But, I don't know how to go there?</string>
```

In your layout file use the reference `chocobar` to set the string to the button,

```
android:text="@string/chocobar"
```

Comment: Yes, I have added android: text=@string/chocobar. 
The error is on the string xml side.

Comment: Did u change the string.xml file as given in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

`<string name="chocobar">I am the passed string for the button. But, I don't know how to go there?</string>`

`name` is for you to identify the `string` when assigning the text to the `Button`

The text between the `>` and `<` is what will get displayed on the `Button`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `string.xml` resource name should not contain any white space. That is the reason why you are getting such an error. It is not good practice to give such a long name to the identifier, even though there is no harm to do so.

**Solution**

```
 string name="chocobar">I am the passed string for the button. But, I don't know how to go there?</string>
```

if you want to access `chocobar` from java code or XML

Answer (score 0):

```
'<string name="string_tag">string</string>'
```

if you want to call the string for xml:

```
'android:text="@string/string_tag"  '
```

...for kotlin or java:

```
'R.string.string_tag'
```

Comment: kotlin and Java does not play any role in this it should be access as `R.string.string_tag` in both . By `android.R.string.string_tag` you are accessing framework's `R.java` .. This answer is utterly Wrong ...